# Removing ListView header borders in Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I am strugglin with styling a ListView in Blend for VS 2015.

[Border image](http://prnt.sc/e6g8en)

I am trying to remove the border with no success so far.
I honestly have no clue which control to edit since I am new to XAML and Blend. 
Also, where do I have to look if I want to edit the text styles and margins?

Any tips would be really helpful!

EDIT: This is my current template. (no styles added are currently doing anything)

```
   <ListView x:Name="osebe_listView" Margin="0,0,40,0"  SelectionMode="Multiple" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="osebe_lw_SelectionChanged">


            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding visible}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1AFFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
                </Style>

            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.Background>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Path Opacity="0.3" Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 1284.873,520.501 C 1284.873,520.501 624.468,520.501 398.000,520.501 C 357.500,520.501 317.795,532.191 321.482,568.667 C 324.750,601.000 376.000,615.067 376.000,615.067 C 376.000,615.067 334.939,618.238 269.047,597.756 C 235.250,587.250 196.701,555.682 160.000,539.000 C 127.000,524.000 96.000,520.501 60.615,520.501 C 50.487,520.501 25.106,520.501 25.106,520.501 C 15.756,520.501 8.106,512.851 8.106,503.501 L 8.106,25.279 C 8.106,15.929 15.756,8.279 25.106,8.279 L 1284.873,8.279 C 1294.223,8.279 1301.873,15.929 1301.873,25.279 L 1301.873,503.501 C 1301.873,512.851 1294.223,520.501 1284.873,520.501 Z"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </ListView.Background>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Naziv podjetja" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nazivPodjetja}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ime}" Width="25"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Priimek" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priimek}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding naslov}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Pošta" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding posta}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mobilna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mobilnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Stacionarna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stacionarnaSt}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="E-naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding eMail}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Skupina" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding skupina}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=helperField}"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: How does your current template look like?

Comment: I added the code to my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `GridViewColumnHeader`.

You can copy the default template by right-clicking on a `GridViewColumnHeader` element in Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy and then modify it as per your requirements:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.4091"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F8F9" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF2F2F2" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD5D5D5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFBDEDFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB7E7FB" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8DD6F7" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8AD1F5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="-9"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1AFFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#FFE3F7FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderHoverBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Margin="1,1,0,0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderPressBorder" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="1,0,0,1"/>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF88CBEB"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF95DAF9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderPressBorder" Value="#FF7A9EB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#FFBCE4F9"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderContent" Value="1,1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: I was looking for GridViewColumnHeader and couldn't find it. This is what I got: http://prntscr.com/e6hdz0

Comment: Just create a new temporary XAML file, add a <GridViewColumnHeader /> element to it by typing in the XAML editor and then right-click on it the "Objects and Timeline" pane. Also note that I included the default template on Windows 10 for you with some slight modifications in my answer. Did you try it?

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: I didn't know you could do that :O  I'll check it out a bit and get it working hopefully. Thanks for now

Comment: Done. Another quick question: How can I apply the GridViewColumnHeader style to a listviews in blend, since I cannot apply the resource to none of listViews' elements?